# Symfony QueryBuilder andWhere for User-Relation not Working

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I want to load items for a given User. Between Item and User lives a One-To-Many relationship.
If I use the following, everything is working well:

```
$result = $em→getRepository(Item::class)→findBy(['user' => $user]);
```

The $result has 3 entries.
Now I have to give additional conditions to the query. So I want to use the queryBuilder insight the repository:

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->andWhere('i.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The result is empty but the query runs without any errors.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
In both cases the $user is the related App\Entity\User entity.

Comment: Not sure but try this : 
`$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')->innerJoin('i.user', 'user')->andWhere('user.id = :user')->setParameter('user', $user)->getQuery()->getResult();`

Comment: I tried this but it is also not working. I tried also $user→getId() but it is also not working. If I'm using the email property of the user, it's working. 
Maybe that's an issue of the Uuid-Id property?

Comment: Maybe, have you got this in your entity before your id delcaration : `@ORM\Id` ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It didn't work because of the Uuid. This works:

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->andWhere('i.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user->getId()->toBinary())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```